# Function is not getting called

Tags: python

I have below code where I have two functions print_menu() and pStockName()

```
def print_menu():
    print ("\t\t\t\t 1. Get Stock Series ")


print ("\t\t\t\t 2. Invoke Stocks.")
print ("\t\t\t\t 3. Generate DC Stock List . ")
print ("\t\t\t\t 4. QUIT")


def pStockName():
    global StockList, fStockList
    pStockList = []
    fStockList = []
    StockList = str(raw_input('Enter pipe separated list of StockS : ')).upper().strip()
    items = StockList.split("|")
    count = len(items)
    print  'Total Distint Stock Count : ', count
    items = list(set(StockList.split("|")))
    # pipelst = StockList.split('|')
    # pipelst = [i.split('-mc')[0] for i in StockList.split('|')]
    # pipelst = [i.replace('-mc','').replace('-MC','').replace('$','').replace('^','') for i in StockList.split('|')]
    pipelst = [i.replace('-mc', '').replace('-MC', '').replace('$', '').replace('^', '') for i in items]
    # pipelst = [Stock.rsplit('-mc',1)[0] for Stock in pipelst]
    filepath = '/location/Stock_data.txt'
    f = open(filepath, 'r')
    for lns in f:
        split_pipe = lns.split(':', 1)
        if split_pipe[0] in pipelst:
            index = pipelst.index(split_pipe[0])
            pStockList = split_pipe[0] + "|"
            fStockList.append(pStockList)
            del pipelst[index]
    # f.close()
    for lns in pipelst:
        print bcolors.red + lns, ' is wrong Stock Name' + bcolors.ENDC
        if lns:
            uResp = str(raw_input('Do You Want To Continue with option 0 [YES|Y|NO|N] : ')).upper().strip()
            if uResp == "NO" or uResp == "N":
                os.system("tput clear")
                print bcolors.FAIL + "\n PLEASE USE OPTION 0 TO ENTER THE Stock NAMES BEFORE PROCEEDING." + bcolors.ENDC
                # StockList = None
                print_menu()
        else:
            pStockName()
    f.close()
```

In above code you must be seeing in 4th last line I am calling print_menu() function. But it is just printing the content of print_menu() function not doing any operation and going to pStockName() function. Follow operation I want to execute from print_menu() function when I am calling it:

```
while choice >= 1 and choice < 4:
    if choice == 4:
        os.system("tput clear")

        if StockList:
            uResp = str(raw_input(
                bcolors.FAIL + 'Do you need to move : ' + StockList + ' ? Press Y To Go Back to Main Menu and N to Quit [YES|Y|NO|N] : ')).upper()
            if uResp == "NO" or uResp == "N":
                print  bcolors.HEADER + "GoodBye." + bcolors.ENDC
                break
```

I mean to say when I am calling print_menu() function in pStockName() function in 4th last line from pStockName() function it should print the content of print_menu() function and when I press 4 it should perform the operation quit. But when I pressing any of the option from 1 to 4 it going to pStockName() function only.

Please help me what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Actually, you are not defining `choice` . Your script have no idea what `choice` is .. :((((

Comment: @Mlwn sorry forgot to paste that. Edited in source code. Please have a look.

Comment: you still didn't assign a value to `choice`

Comment: Surely you could provide a more minimal example to illustrate this problem.

Comment: You have nothing that reads an input after calling `print_menu()`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit new here, but I do not see where you assign the keyboard input into variable "choice". Therefore, the program will not recognize what the end user input is. My suggestion is to assign "choice" into raw_input Like so:

```
choice = raw_input()
if choice == "4": # alternatively, perform int(choice) == 4
   print ("yes")
```

I hope this helps!